# gradle subproject dependency version overridden in root project

Tags: java, gradle, spring-security

I am configuring Multi project build using Gradle.

I have a root project which is dependent on three other project Project A, B, & C.

Suppose Project B has a dependency to Spring Security
e.g. compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '3.2.4.RELEASE'

Dependency version get resolved well for Project B.

But when I try to resolve dependency on Root Project version of Spring Security get changed 4.0.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle uses a "newest-version-wins" [conflict resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:version_conflicts) by default. So if root project or any other project it depends on uses a newer (4.0.4.RELEASE) version of spring-security, then the resolved version for root project will be that newer version.